# Can PHP constants be called in HTML form tag?

Tags: php, html

While working on a project, we've created global constants in a PHP file. When accessing these global constants in HTML to specify the name for POST variables, is the following correct:

```
<input type="text" name="<?PHPecho POST_CONSTANT;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Constant" />
```

Is it more appropriate to use `htmlspecialchars(CONSTANT);`?

Comment: `<?PHPecho POST_CONSTANT;?>" ` needs a space before the echo

Comment: The usage of `htmlspecialchars` depends on the content of a variable/constant.

Comment: I'll confirm that this was a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain, but I think the `php` needs to be lowercase in the open tag and you need a space (or other whitespace character) before the `echo`.

```
<input name="<?php echo POST_CONSTANT; ?>" />
```

If you anticipate the constants ever having special characters then, yes, you should probably escape them. If it is just values you define as simple alphanumeric strings, then probably not necessary.